# Problems with clicking a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I wanted the program to click the 'PLAY' Button on spotify to play a song, but sadly I get this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function

The code I tried is

```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[text()='PLAY']")))
  time.sleep(1)
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='PLAY']"))
```

Can someone help me to find the button and click it, I tried also the

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='PLAY']").click()
```

But I get the error element is not interactable

Comment: You're probably going to have better luck triggering a multimedia play event (whatever the "play" button on a multimedia keyboard sends) or [using the Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/).

Comment: @Chris do you know a way maybe to do that,the only thing I found is sending the space button press but it only continues the last song I played and doesn't play the song sadly

Comment: What operating system are you on? I mostly know Linux, where you'd probably send `XF86AudioPlay`. There might be a library that abstracts over this implementation detail.

Comment: inspect and share the screenshot of the webelements on website. maybe you have issue with your xpath.

Comment: @SaidYusifli I'm sorry if the question is stupid but I'm new to everything, here it is [pic](https://i.imgur.com/gBtXd8Y.png)

Comment: try this one driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='TrackListHeader__button TrackListHeader__button--top']//button").click();

Answer (score 0):

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
>   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='TrackListHeader__button
>   TrackListHeader__button--top']//button")));
>
> Thread.sleep(1000);
>
> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='TrackListHeader__button
>   TrackListHeader__button--top']//button").click();

also try this one

Answer (score 0):

EC has a good method for verifying element is clickable before making an action `element_to_be_clickable`.

Also, I found over 20 elements on Spotify using your XPath, so I modified it to look for `button` instead of `*`.

**Try this:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='PLAY']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='PLAY']").click()
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!